# React: Trying to render images from public folder dynamically in iterated component

Tags: reactjs, image, dynamic, render, public

New here with my first question. I have searched for several days now, and cant figure what I am doing wrong. I am new to React and development as a whole, so that most likely is my biggest hurdle, however, from what I can tell, this should work.

I am trying to render images in an iterated component dynamically. Images are hosted locally in the public folder. While I'm working this out, I'm using JSON server for my data to iterate from. When I use the full path in my component all is fine:

```
<figure className="stone__card">
    <img className="stone__img"
        src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/img/stone/BiancoSivec1.jpg`}
        alt="BiancoSivec"
    />
    <h3 className="stone__card-head">Bianco Sivec</h3>
    <p className="stone__card-type">Marbre</p>
</figure>
```

However, since I have many items I need to iterate through and render, I try the same dynamically, and just the images are broken:

```
<figure className="stone__card">
  <img className="stone__img"
    src={stone.image}
    alt={stone.name}
   />
  <h3 className="stone__card-head">{stone.name}</h3>
  <p className="stone__card-type">{stone.type}</p>
</figure>
```

When I console.log stone.image, I receive the appropriate data:

```
{`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/img/stone/BiancoSivec1.jpg`}
```

I have tried fiddling with removing/adding braces in my db.json file to no avail. Am I missing something, or just not allowed to do this? I have been to React docs Using Public Folder and not finding anything there either. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Here is my db.json file i'm using:

```
{
    "stones": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Bianco Sivec",
            "type": "Marbre",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "{`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/img/stone/BiancoSivec1.jpg`}"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Imperial White",
            "type": "Marbre",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "{`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/img/stone/ImperialWhite1.jpg`}"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Fantasy White",
            "type": "Marbre",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "{`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/img/stone/FantasyWhite1.jpg`}"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Infinito",
            "type": "Marbre",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "{`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/img/stone/Infinito1.jpg`}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is image of actual log:

[Image of log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Lri.png)

Comment: When you console.log `stone.image` you should receive a string with the public URL included. If you receive `{${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/img/stone/BiancoSivec1.jpg}`, then you probably forgot to use template literals. How do you store and/or load the URLs of the images?

Comment: Hi, could you provide an example of your JSON file where yo have the images info?

Comment: Hi Zsolt, the missing template literals were an error in how I posted the question. Its fixed now. Unless you mean that my log should be wrapped in "" which it is not.

Comment: Hi lissettdm, I posted the db.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON format does not support template literals and there are no env variables.

Therefore, you need to remove the template literals and bring your `json` file to the following form, so that you get a relative path:

```json
{
    "stones": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Bianco Sivec",
            "type": "Marbre",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/BiancoSivec1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Imperial White",
            "type": "Marbre",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/ImperialWhite1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Fantasy White",
            "type": "Marbre",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/FantasyWhite1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "important": true,
            "name": "Infinito",
            "type": "Marbre",
            "color": "Blanc",
            "origin": "Macédoine",
            "finish": "Poli",
            "thickness": "3cm, 2cm",
            "image": "assets/img/stone/Infinito1.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

And in the component, using template literals, convert relative link to an absolute path.

```
<figure className="stone__card">
  <img className="stone__img"
    src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/${stone.image}`}
    alt={stone.name}
   />
  <h3 className="stone__card-head">{stone.name}</h3>
  <p className="stone__card-type">{stone.type}</p>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. I understand why it wasn't working now too.

Comment: @JonDennis have you achieved the desired result?